# How to order collection by json attribute in Laravel

Tags: laravel

In my code, i have a collection object. One part of the collection object is structured as follows

```
"id" => 1
"rate" => "{"p_1":"1","p_2":"2","p_3":"2.3","p_4":"3.5"}"
"currency" => 1
"desc" => "TEST"
```

In the above instance i have a key called `rate`, which has a json string as value.

What i want to do is sort the collection object by value `p_1` contained in the `range` key.

Comment: Your question is unclear. In what way do you want to order `p_1` in `rate`?

Comment: What Laravel version are you using?

Comment: @NicolaWorthington i want to order all the objects of the collection by the p_1.

Comment: @Jerodev i am using laravel 5.4

Comment: @AMDEV : did you fixed this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to decode the JSON string before ordering:

```
$collection->sortBy(function(array $item) {
    return json_decode($item->rate)->p_1;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sortBy()` to sort collection in laravel

```
$collection->sortBy(function($item) {
  return $item->rate->p_1;
});
```

here `$collection` is your laravel result which gives by default, you can explicitly convert it by using `collect` method as well

Check [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-sortby) for more details